# Styling java mail (without user interaction)

Tags: android, jakarta-mail

I am able to send mail without user interaction through java mail.
How can I style (size, bold, color) the text (body) of the mail?

**Edit:**
I'm using code I found to [send mail without user interaction][1].

Comment: Giving more details increases the likelihood and quality of answers. What part of the API are you using? Show us a code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You Bill Shannon you are right i need to send html text, and Krylez as well.

The way to do it is to change this part of the send() method in Mail Class/Mail.jave file:

// setup message body

BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

messageBodyPart.setText(_body);

_multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

To this

// setup message body

BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

messageBodyPart.setContent(_body, "text/html");

_multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

Comment: another way is to set a DataHandler like this : DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(_body.getByted(), "text/html")); and setDataHandler for messageBodyPart like this : messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(dh);

Answer (score 1):

[As described in the JavaMail FAQ, send html text.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#sendrich)

Comment: i dont understand i need an intent for it wich i dont want? intent to put extra html.fromhtml but i can only send a string

Comment: msg.setText("<html>whatever</html>", "utf-8", "html");